# How to get the deepest node of XML in as3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

My XML is,

```
<books>
  <book>
    <chapter number="1">
        <chapter number="2">
            <chapter number="3">
            </chapter>
        </chapter>
    </chapter>
  </book>
</books>
```

I want to get the deepest node like an **XML** using loop. I tried something like

```
    private function getDeepNode(node:XML):XML
    {
        var nextLevelNode:XML = XML(node.chapter[0]);
        if (nextLevelNode.children().length() > 0)
        {
            return getDeepNode(nextLevelNode);
        }
        else
        {
            return nextLevelNode;
        }
    }
```

But i couldn't get it. I don't know what is my mistake. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the definition of "deepest" that you have. If you just want to get the reference to the last node, you can use XML `..` operator:

```
        var xml:XML = <books>
            <book>
                <chapter number="1">
                    <chapter number="2">
                        <chapter number="3">
                        </chapter>
                    </chapter>
                </chapter>
            </book>
        </books>

        var lastNode:XML = res[res.length()-1];

        trace("last", lastNode.@number[0]);
```

output:

```
        [trace] last 3
```

Comment: it's so good. If I want to get some other information about that node, I don't have chance to get it. so I want to do this one using loop with recursion.

Comment: the reference to the node is _res[res.length()-1]_, I updated answer